# Camel Json to XML, what about XML entities?

Tags: json, xml, apache-camel, xml-entities

Using Camel transformation, Json to XML,
With

> ```
>     <dataFormats>
>         <xmljson id="xmljson"/>
>         <xmljson id="xmljsonWithOptions" forceTopLevelObject="true" trimSpaces="true" rootName="root"
>                  skipNamespaces="true" removeNamespacePrefixes="true" expandableProperties="d e"/>
>     </dataFormats>
> ```

And applying the transformation with :

> ```
>  <unmarshal ref="xmljsonWithOptions"/>
> ```

I can indeed transform Json into XML, but there is no xml entities transformation,

Typically, if some text was containing "&" this caracter, it is not rewrittent into "&amp;",

Any way to do this ?

Comment: Seems an incredibly basic bug if that's true. Raise a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't a bug, it was a false positive issue.
The component's behavior is the expected one. Just me who should take more attention.
Sorry for disturbing.